# Chose next proxy from listbox with timer vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi start a new application to generate traffic and i have 3 list boxs one for the referral links , one for the proxys , and one for the users agents.
My question is i have add tree timers to my form and i need to change the referral link on the textbox each 10 secs for example 
How can i archive this?
This is my code

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Net
Imports System
Public Class Form3
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\proxy.txt"
Dim x As Integer
Dim rfe As Integer
Dim prx As Integer
Dim users As Integer
Dim label As String
Public proxy(2000) As String
Public index As Integer = 0
Public max_proxys As Integer = 0
Dim a As String
Dim start_check As Integer = 0
<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function InternetSetOption(ByVal hInternet As IntPtr, ByVal dwOption As Integer, ByVal lpBuffer As IntPtr, ByVal lpdwBufferLength As Integer) As Boolean
End Function
Public Structure Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
    Public dwAccessType As Integer
    Public proxy As IntPtr
    Public proxyBypass As IntPtr
End Structure
Private Sub UseProxy(ByVal strProxy As String)
    Const INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY As Integer = 38
    Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY As Integer = 3

    Dim struct_IPI As Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO

    struct_IPI.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY
    struct_IPI.proxy = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(strProxy)
    struct_IPI.proxyBypass = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local")

    Dim intptrStruct As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI))

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(struct_IPI, intptrStruct, True)

    Dim iReturn As Boolean = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, intptrStruct, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI))
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timerreferrals.Enabled = True
    UseProxy(Label8.Text)
    Dim wr As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(TextBox1.Text)
    wr.Referer = TextBox5.Text
    wr.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36"
    Dim resp As HttpWebResponse = wr.GetResponse
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
    Button1.Enabled = False
    Button2.Enabled = True
    Button3.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    Button1.Enabled = True
    Button2.Enabled = False
    Button3.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    x = x + 1
    If x = TextBox2.Text Then
        WebBrowser1.Refresh()
        x = 0
        Label4.Text = Val(Label4.Text) + 1

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox2.Text = 10
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Label8.Text = (TextBox3.Text & ":" & TextBox4.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then


        Dim path As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path))

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Label13_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label13.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    If OpenFileDialog2.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then


        Dim path As String = OpenFileDialog2.FileName

        ListBox2.Items.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path))

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Label14_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label14.Click
    ListBox2.Items.Clear()

End Sub

Private Sub Label15_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label15.Click
    ListBox4.Items.Clear()

End Sub

Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    If OpenFileDialog3.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then


        Dim path As String = OpenFileDialog3.FileName

        ListBox4.Items.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path))

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timerreferrals.Tick
    rfe = rfe + 1
    Dim counthit = 0
    TextBox5.Text = ListBox1.Text
    Label17.Text = rfe
    Timerreferrals.Interval = 1000
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    If rfe = TextBox6.Text Then
        For Each o As Object In ListBox1.Items
            'sb.AppendLine(o)
            'TextBox5.Text = sb.ToString
            ' rfe = 0
            counthit = counthit + 1

        Next
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = Me.ListBox1.SelectedIndex + 1


        TextBox5.Text = ListBox1.Text
        rfe = 0
    End If




    If TextBox6.Text = "" Then
        Return

    End If


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: i have tried like this but no sucess For Each line As String In ListBox1.Items
        TextBox5.Text = line


    Next

Comment: No one is likely to be able to help you without some kind of screenshot showing the layout of these controls and an **explanation** of the values that are in them.

Comment: Sorry for that here it is the print from the app and how its works http://imgur.com/a/4kXKL

Comment: My question is i have manage to get each time the timer its finish to change the current item from a listbox but the wen its come the final item its make a error out of range @Idle_Mind

Comment: how can i detect wen there is no more items there and go the first again @Idle_Mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is i have manage to get each time the timer its finish to
>   change the current item from a listbox but the wen its come the final
>   item its make a error out of range ... how can i detect wen there is
>   no more items there and go the first again

Gotcha...so change:

```
ListBox1.SelectedIndex = Me.ListBox1.SelectedIndex + 1
```

To something like:

```
If Me.ListBox1.SelectedIndex < Me.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then
    Me.ListBox1.SelectedIndex = Me.ListBox1.SelectedIndex + 1
Else
    Me.ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
End If
```

Comment: Tanks You you have saved my skin i have try all much every possible but  i dint get tanks its work perfect @Idle_Mind